# Как рисовать на JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, таблицы, рисование

Создаю программу гитарных аккордов в Swing. В программе реализовал картинку "гитарный гриф" на JLabel следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача такова: задать на данном лейбле координаты появления точек в виде неровной сетки, т. е. простым языком чтобы пользователю при нажатии определенной кнопки появлялись эти точки, а потом сменялись при нажатии другой. Проблема еще в том, что необходимо, чтобы пользователю при нажатии на специальную кнопку появились все доступные точки, и он бы смог создать свою собственную комбинацию. Долго рывшись на просторах интернета набрел вот на [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55736459/how-to-draw-on-jlabel-with-image-icon-in-java) топик и в итоге встал в ступор. Ведь в классе Graphics2D я не нашел метода, который бы стирал конкретные точки и рисовал бы другие. Какими методами можно было бы реализовать данную задумку? Очень надеюсь на помощь в данном пет проекте.

*P.S. Я кодить умею, хотя еще полный чайник, но пара полноценных проектов уже за спиной, так что пожалуйста, не посылайте меня "курить" документацию =)*

Answer (score 0):

Стереть картинку - это закрасить её цветом фона. Можно квадратик поверх нарисовать - типо как закрашивать забор. После этого можно рисовать заново.

Comment: всё же это не ответ(